# Does HSBC publish a balance sheet for each of its branch in US, UK and HK?

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, stock-exchanges, balance-sheet, quarterly-report

So HSBC is listed on the New York Stock Exchange, London Stock Exchange and the Stock Exchange of Hong Kong Limited.

I can only find one report/balance sheet for every fiscal period (quarterly and annually). The same report is published on HSBC's US' and HK' website with the links below. So could it be that HSBC only publishes one report that comprises the results from all 3 branches or is there actually one report for each branch?

https://www.hsbc.com/investors/results-and-announcements

https://www.about.hsbc.com.hk/investor-relations

Comment: Slightly nitpicking, I know, but "_branches_" is probably not the best word to use. At least in the UK, a "bank branch" refers to each of its main bricks-and-mortar presences on the high-street (or wherever). I don't know if HSBC has an official term, but "_Divisions_" or "_Operations_" might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the non-Group reports all here:
https://www.hsbc.com/investors/results-and-announcements/all-reporting/subsidiaries?page=1&take=20&reporting-type=annual&years=2019

You can filter by quarterly or annual